# Regex Question. Match pattern in a string

Tags: regex

basically in need that a whole string is a match if it has the following pattern:

DIGITS SPACE WORDS(min. 1 to a max of 3.) SPACE

So the following string will be a match:

```
30 boxes 30 boxes 30 boxes boxes boxes
```

But the following won't match:

```
30 boxes 30 boxes boxes boxes boxes 30 boxes
```

NOTE: the last character in a row is a space

I have the following regex up until now:

```
(\d+)(\s)(([a-zA-Z]+)(\s)){1,3}
```

Comment: By "strings" do you mean "letters" or "words" or something else? Also, I can't understand why the first example matches and the seconds one does not.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: The 1st one is satisfied because between each pair of integers there are a max. of 3 words i.e. boxes is written 3 times.
In the 2nd instance, there is boxes written 4 times which should be incorrect as stated by the regex statement {1,3}

Comment: Try `^(?:\d+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+){1,3}\s*)+$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PiihOI/1)

Comment: @wiktor feel free to post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

```
^(?:\d+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+){1,3}\s*)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PiihOI/1)

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+){1,3}\s*)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+){1,3}` - one, two or three occurrences of

    - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
    - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Your pattern doesn't work for `"30 boxes 30 boxes boxes boxes boxes 30 boxes "` case.

Comment: @JohnyL It should fail, so it works. `boxes boxes boxes boxes` contains 4 words and the requirement is *min. 1 to a max of 3.*.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "30 boxes 30 boxes boxes boxes boxes 30 boxes ";
var pattern = @"(?i)^(\d+(\s+[a-z]+\s*)+){1,3}$";
WriteLine($"Is match: {Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern)}"); // => Is match: true
```